# Ruby Shoes calculator functions don't run (array related error?)

Tags: ruby, arrays, shoes

I tried to code a simple calculator with GUI in Ruby Shoes.

The idea was to save the numbers on the buttons you press in an array and then get an integer from that (loop that adds `array[i] * {arraydepth}` to the number). Then I would clear the stack that holds my "result" display and replace it with a new textfield that shows the result (currently it just says "changed" as I didn't get that far yet.)

My methods don't work. When I try to add a number to my array with this function

```
def addToVar(number)

  if choosingVar2
    var2Counter += 1
    var2[var2Counter] = number
  else
    var1Counter += 1
    var1[var1Counter] = number
  end

  transToNumber

rescue
  @p.clear { para \"edited\" }

end
```

it doesn't execute any of the code before the `rescue`. I tried to put an `alert("alert")` before the `if`/`else` stuff. That worked, but everything after the first `if` and before the `rescue` isn't executed. Why?

I get the same problem when I try to get an integer from the values stored in the array with the following function

```
def transToNumber

  mult = 1
  while var1Counter > 0
    var1Num += var1[var1Counter] * mult
    mult *= 10
    var1Counter -= 1
  end

  mult = 1
  while var2Counter > 0
    var2Num += var2[var2Counter] * mult
    mult *= 10
    var2Counter -=1
  end

  @p.clear { para \"edited\" }

end
```

I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the array.

[Complete code here.](http://www.beetxt.com/brV/)

Comment: Please don't use links to publish your code. Questions on Stack Overflow are liable to be read by many others at any date in the future, and you cannot vouch for the reliability of other web sources.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having deals with variable scope. All of the variables defined at the top of your code (e.g., `choosingVar2`) are local and are not visible to your methods like `addToVar(number)`. Ruby is throwing an error about this, but you are not seeing any helpful error messages because of the generic `rescue` statement, which is catching but not reporting exceptions. This is why it looks like the code is not executing.

First thing I would do is either comment out the `rescue` statements you have or make them display a generic message so you can debug more easily:

```
rescue Exception => msg
    puts msg
```

Second, you can simply make all of your initial variables instance variables, which will make them accessible in your methods (within the scope of what I assume is a class/object in Shoes):

```
@var2 = []
@var2[0] = 0
@var2Counter = 0
@var2Num = 0

@choosingVar2 = false

def addToVar(number)
  if @choosingVar2 
        @var2Counter += 1
        @var2[@var2Counter] = number
...
```

For more about variable scope you can find lots of tutorials and good write-ups online (or in ruby docs themselves). Here is one example: http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/variables/

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I only added the "rescue" because I didn't get any error messages and wanted to see if and exception was at fault.

Even with "rescue Exception => msg  puts msg" I don't get anything.

(Is "cmd -> Shoes Calculator.rb" a wrong way to run it?)

Comment: Also is there a way to tell shoes to just crash the program if a thread throws an exception?

(sorry for double comment, theres a 5min edit limit :<)